# React Native Picker Issue Android

Tags: android, react-native

My package.json dependancies looks as below

```
"dependencies": {
    "@remobile/react-native-cordova": "^1.0.9",
    "@remobile/react-native-file-transfer": "^1.0.6",
    "react": "^15.4.1",
    "react-native": "^0.38.0",
    "react-native-android-sms-listener": "^0.4.0",
    "react-native-chart": "^1.0.8-beta",
    "react-native-facebook-login": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.24.1",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.2.5",
    "react-native-keychain": "^0.3.2",
    "react-native-navbar": "^1.4.2",
    "react-native-onesignal": "^3.0.3",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^2.0.0"
  }
```

All of a sudden it started throwing below error.

[image]

Picker Code is as below

```
<View style={{marginRight:5,marginLeft:5, marginTop:5, marginBottom:5}}>
              <Text style={commonStyles.label}>Type of business</Text>
              <Picker
                style={{color: darkTextColor, marginLeft:12}}
                ref="Type of business"
                selectedValue={this.props.application.typeOfBusiness}
                onValueChange={(toi) => this.onUpdate('typeOfBusiness', toi)}>
                {typeOfBusinessLabels.map((val)=> <Picker.Item key={val} label={val} value={val}/>)}
              </Picker>
              <View style={{borderColor:'#29A1C9', borderBottomWidth:1}}></View>
            </View>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was an issue with RN bundle. Was fixed automatically.